# Take v-model value and create loop with v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a input field. This field is contain number. I want to take this number and use this number with for loop.

On my example there is number 5 inside input field and i want to write `li` five times. Ok it is work! But when i change number to 10 there is just write 10 it is not inside loop anymore and it is not show 10 times li loop.

How can i show dynamically v-model value with v-for?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    uTopX: 5,
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="uTopX">Top X</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="uTopX" v-model="uTopX" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <ul>
    <li v-for="n in uTopX">
      {{n}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try v-model.number https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `v-model` returns anything you enter as string.

using `v-model.number` is the simplest solution.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
      uTopX: 5,
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="uTopX">Top X</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="uTopX" v-model.number="uTopX" type="number">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <ul>
    <li v-for="n in uTopX">
      {{n}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As Emīls Gulbis pointed out in the main comments, having Vue automatically typecast the input to a number is better solution and saves writing a lot of code.

Comment: That sure does. I was not aware of that vue implementation.

Comment: Maybe I should edit this post, in case someone should stumble upon this will get them the correct answer. Some people don't read comments, they just go through answers.

Comment: Sure. Since Emils did not put it in an answer you may as well.